# Python + Firestore : query specific fields from all documents in a collection

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read a specific field from all documents in a collection without listing all fields. For example, I want to only read and print **Brand** from all documents in **Donut** collection. But right now my python script is printing all fields in all documents (code obtained from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart). I couldn't find the answer in it. can someone help?  [image: Database Structure]

Comment: I don't think this is possible through the Admin SDKs (I'm sure it is not possible through the Node.js Admin SDK). However it is possible with the Firestore REST API with a [DocumentMask](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the codes below, it will print all Brand from all documents in Donut collection:

```
users_ref = db.collection('Donut')
docs = users_ref.stream()
for doc in docs:
    brand = u'{}'.format(doc.to_dict()['Brand'])
    print(brand)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want one field you can use the get() method of the DocumentSnapshot. The code below should work for what you want:

```
users_ref = db.collection('Donut')
docs = users_ref.stream()
for doc in docs:
    brand = doc.get('Brand')
    print(brand)
```