# Read Data | Cloud Firestore and Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `commodity_price` table within `Firestore` having the following structure -

`collection` / `document` / `collection` / `document` / `field`

Following is the type of the information contained -

`commodity_price` (the table) / `city` / `commodity` / `date` / `price`

Questions -

1. How do I get a list of all the cities in the table?
2. How do I get a list of cities having data for a specific date?

I tried using the following code but returns 0 records -

```
docs = db.collection('commodity_price').get() 
for doc in docs:
    print(doc.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, on how to get a list of all the `cities` in your `commodity_price` document I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411878/python-firestore-query-specific-fields-from-all-documents-in-a-collection) which has an accepted answer which I think you can adapt to suit you use case. Something like:

```
docs = db.collection('commodity_price') 
results = docs.stream()
for result in results:
    city = u'{}'.format(doc.to_dict()['city'])
    print(city)
```

Addressing your second question, on how to get a list of `cities` filtering by a specific date. I think you could use a similar approach as before, but including a filter for the date that you want, for example:

```
date = "2022-01-01"

docs = db.collection('commodity_price') 
docs.where("date", "==", date)
results = docs.stream()
for result in results:
    city = u'{}'.format(doc.to_dict()['city'])
    print(city)
```

This last solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47005940/12512650) and [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#pythonasync_4)